# Solution of the heat equation and Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We consider the heat equation: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,x)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(r,x),(r,x) \in \mathbb{R}^*_+ \times \mathbb{R}.$

We want to find a solution of this equation using Fourier series.

I know that $p(r,x)=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{2 \pi i k x}e^{-(2 \pi k)^2 r},(r,x) \in \mathbb{R}^*_+ \times \mathbb{R}$ is a solution, and we can prove it by showing that $p$ verifies the equation.

Given the equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(r,x)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(r,x),$ how to obtain the expression of $p$?

Comment: Well, also, you'll need numerical coefficients for each term $e^{2\pi ikx}e^{-(2\pi k)^2r}$, which are usually determined by the initial condition, that is, the Fourier expansion of the initial function at $r=0$...

Comment: This might be useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3283231/1104384

Comment: What, in your opinion, does ‘$\mathbb{R}^*_+$’ mean?

Comment: @Aruralreader $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ is the set of strictly positive reals, unless there is some other convention in the English world. The $*$ is for "without $0$" and the $+$ is for "positive or zero". Very common notations in France at least.

Comment: @BrunoB: thank you, I learned something new.

Comment: If the domain of $x$ is infinite, why is $k$ limited to the integers?